# Only one network interface active at a time in Android

Tags: wi-fi, networking, connection-issues, mobile-data, mobile-network

I was looking into the network configurations in Android devices. Android makes WI-FI as the default network preference. And I noticed only one network interface can be active at a time in Android. Even `ifconfig` shows both wi-fi and `rmnet_data0` interfaces UP, the routing table has routing rules applied for only one interface.

The `rmnet_data0` interface doesn't have RUNNING state when wi-fi is ON. Can you please point me to which file in AOSP file that this restriction implementation has been made (like register only one net_device)? In `ConnectivityManager.java` file I saw that `TYPE_WI-FI` was made the default interface, but I could not find how and where they register and unregister network interfaces when WI-FI is present or not.